# make multiple Markers google map by address or pincode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

i want to make multiple  Markers google map by address or pincode like

i just add address or pincode in array and i will made multiple marker google map

for example

```
 var address = new Array('Canada','Newyourk')

          or may be pincode

     var address = new Array('123456','654321')
```

my basic is `html` and `javascript`

Comment: i have some pincode no. and i have to set multiple Markers google map by address or pincode

Comment: i have found a example https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geocoding-simple but it is not multiple

Comment: [Fusion Tables Google Map API Layers](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/fusion_tables.html)
[Google Dev](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)
Read the API and try something and update your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done using Geocoding service of the API. More on this topis here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding and here: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_exists.

I also advice you to read the whole API documentation. It's one the best API documentations out there with lots of useful examples and guides.

Comment: he,`Jan Wrm` you give me a single marker example but i want multiple

Comment: Well at least its a good starting point. You would probably have to make a function for that - loop through your records and convert them to geocodes.